# mplementing a Full-Screen Loader in Project - Need Assistance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native, mobile-development

I have an existing React Native Expo project with 50 screens. I want to create a spinner loader component that can be easily integrated into my entire project without explicitly adding it to each of the 50 screens

i tried making 2 new files 1 is loader and other one is loaderwrapper and i wrap it in appnavigator but doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the loading component inside the routes, and to show the modal you can use a provider(ContextApi of react) or some lib to manage a global state, ex: zustand.

And when you set the global state to true, the loading will pop up, wherever screen you're.

Hops this helps.

Comment: i have multiple buttons in single screen how can i show spinner on all of the buttons

Comment: create a component with the prop isLoading, and when you want to show the loading see this prop to true, and inside the component verify if the isLoading && <Spinner/> something like this. Share the code, this will allow people to understand much better your problem and helps to fix it.